# Is Header or Javascript better for redirecting in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to redirect users to a specific page after a login. Are both equally effective? or is one better than the other?

Thanks

Comment: How is printing a specific text (JS redirect) a PHP redirect?

Comment: A Javascript redirect can redirect even if a page is loaded (Header already sent), php cannot do that.

Comment: Each method has it's advantages. Use the one that suits the given circumstances of your site.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare both methods!

JavaScript will only run on the client side, therefore you need to send HTML first, then execute the redirection.
Using PHP, you can directly forward the user. This is  not only faster, but also the only applicable choice in terms of usablity.

You will also have a problem if JavaScript is disabled or you have got an error in your JS scripts (for whatever reason). Well, you could counter by using HTML meta redirects, but the pros of using server-side redirects just predominate.

Comment: And infinitely faster if the client doesn't support/understand JavaScript.

Comment: Not to mention the redirect is dead if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to client side JS, an HTTP redirect will:

- Require less data to be send to the client for it to process the redirect instruction
- Not cause the browser to behave badly when the back button is pressed
- Work in browsers with JS blocked / disabled / otherwise failing

An HTTP Location header is almost always the better approach.

Comment: - Be properly using the facilities and specifications of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

One is server side (php) and the other is client side (js).

*Usually* it's done server side, so it's a transparent redirection (doesn't pollute browser history, back button, etc). I repeat: *usually* but it's not a rule.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is faster - the whole page doesn't have to load first. You can just send the header and exit the script.